# RabbitMQ high availability in windows10

Tags: windows, rabbitmq, high-availability, lan

I have two machines windows in each machine i have a RabbitMQ server.

Can I implement the high availability approach with RabbitMQ in windows nodes in the same LAN ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You must use 3 servers, not two.

Please see the documentation:

- https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html
- https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html
- You should not use classic mirrored queues. Instead, use quorum queues - https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html